# jQuery / PHP - Different Labels depending on Value of DIV

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have two divs, `<div class="number"></div>` and `<div class="label"></div>`.

I would like to devise an if/else statement, so that if the value in "number" is 1, it returns a label of, for example, "User", whereas if the number is 2 or higher, it changes to "Users".

Is there a way to check the value of .number and then return the label based on it?

Also, there will be 5 instances of "number" and "label" on the same page.  Each number will be returned by querying its value from a database (Wordpress Custom Field Meta).

Also, the label will be different for each instance, the first might be "Users" whereas the second could be "Products", etc.

How would I do what I need?

Here is an example of my code:

```
<div class="data-item employees">
     <div class="number"><?php echo $sc_data_employees; ?></div>
     <div class="label"></div>
</div>
<div class="data-item products">
     <div class="number"><?php echo $sc_data_products; ?></div>
     <div class="label"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: When you say 'value in number` do you mean the text, like `<div>1</div>`?

Comment: Yes, it will be a plain text number like "20" or "3" or "1000", etc

Comment: So you want to change the contents of label based on the contents of number?

Comment: Yes, thats exactly right

Comment: This sort of thing should be done in PHP, before the document is served, since you're getting the data from a database anyway. Unless you're using AJAX, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$('.number').each(function(){
    $(this).next('.label').html( ($(this).text()==1)?'user':'users');
});​​​​​​​​
```

This will run through all elements of class number and change the next instance of element label. Depending on how your divs are arranged, you may need to change .next() to another function.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/UQmL4/1/)**.

Update: Based on your revisions, try this:

```
$('.number').each(function(){
    var plural = $(this).parent().attr('class').split(' ')[1];
    var singular = plural.substring(0, plural.length - 1);
    $(this).next('.label').html( ($(this).text()==1)?singular:plural);
});​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/UQmL4/4/)**.

Comment: what if I want to have a different label for each one?  This looks like it works good, but I'd want a different label for each one, for example the first might be "users" whereas the next might be "products"?  Sorry, I should have mentioend that in the original question

Comment: Can you post the HTML that you're actually using? This way I can create something that will fit exactly.

Comment: OK, based on that code my answer should still work. Sample jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/UQmL4/2/

Comment: Yes but how would you set a different label text for each one? Your sample Fiddle has "users" used on each one, but for example, based on my code above, the first label should say employee/employees, and the second should say product/products, so on and so forth

Comment: Ooooh I didn't realize you needed that. Hold on, update coming.

Comment: Perfect. Very clever! I appreciate your help and my understanding of javascript just went up a notch too!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var users = parseInt($(".number").text(),10);
var label = (users == 1) ? "user" : "users";
$(".label").text(label);
```

If the number of users will not be a whole number, such as `12.3456`, use `parseFloat()` instead of `parseInt()`

Comment: @Blazemonger Thanks for the fix - I think we messed up each others edits as we were fixing it :)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can do this before outputting to the browser with PHP.

```
$number = 1; // The number from your database

$text = ($number == 1) ? "User" : "Users"; //

$output = '<div class="number">{$number}</div>
           <div class="label">{$text}</div>';

echo $output;
```